# mysql 4.1.22 select command returns no rows when using distinct with order by

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: glgroup and glref

```
CREATE TABLE `glgroup` (
  `GLREFID` varchar(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `GLREFNO` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`GLREFID`,`GLREFNO`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `glref` (
  `GLREFNO` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `GLDESC` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `GLCUR` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `GLADDFIELD` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `GLADDFIELD2` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `GLADDFIELD3` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `GLADDFIELDDESC` tinytext,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`GLREFNO`,`GLCUR`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  GLREF.GLREFNO,
  GLREF.GLDESC
FROM GLGROUP,
  GLREF
WHERE GLGROUP.GLREFID = '07'
    AND GLGROUP.GLREFNO = GLREF.GLREFNO
ORDER BY GLREF.GLREFNO;
```

Sometimes (quite often), this query returns no rows. If I remove `order by` clause, it returns 76 rows (when it runs correctly, it returns 76 rows too), if I remove both `distinct` and `order by` clause, it returns 697 rows.
the problem is that, this query is in app code and I cannot modify it. What can I do?

Comment: If you can't modify the query and the query doesn't work, then I don't know what else we can tell you. There's objectively nothing wrong with the query (unless there are no results for `GLREFID` when it's `'07'`). Maybe you can upgrade to a version of MySQL released sometime in the last decade?

Comment: tks for your rep, tables have data, just remove order by, 76 rows returned! right after i restart mysql service, the query returns rows as expected, but after that (about 30 minutes), it returns nothing ?? i just wonder if i had something wrong with my config parameters ? which parameters should i look into ?? any advices ?

Comment: It may very well be a bug in that version of MySQL. If a query stops behaving correctly after arbitrary periods of time, with no change in the data (i.e., no inserts, deletes or updates on the relevant tables), then the problem is either in hardware (e.g., failing RAM) or in the database software itself.

Comment: tks u siride. i think i had something wrong with my memory configuration. will update if i found sth.